# IPhone App using Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I have an IPhone game app idea that will use Google Maps and was wondering if I could charge for a app that used Google Maps? This will be like a mashup.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can but you have to pay for their enterprise license.  If you do not charge for it or you are just developing it - it is free.

http://www.google.com/enterprise/maps/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can charge for it and no, you do not have to pay for an enterprise license. Mobile Applications are excepted from the rule saying that applications using Google Maps have to be free.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

9.1.1 General Rules.

(a) Free Access (No Fees). Your Maps API Implementation must be generally accessible to users without charge and must not require a fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access. This rule applies to Your Content and any other content in your Maps API Implementation, whether Your Content or the other content is in existence now or is added later.

9.1.2 Exceptions.

(b) Mobile Applications. The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.

Comment: Thanks for this, Google Sales were very frustrating and werent very direct they kept pushing their premier license